# What is the method to seal a concrete roof?

Tags: roof, leak, waterproofing, roofing

We are staying in a home which has a concrete roof. Now we are facing leakage in the roof during rainy seasons. What do we have to do? How do we protect the roof from leaks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Concrete itself is not waterproof, in fact, it's more like a sponge, so concrete alone is never used to create an impermeable surface. You haven't provided much info - is the roof flat, sloped? What is already up there?  There are tons of different waterproofing methods available.

Going under the assumption that it was properly waterproofed at some point, you need to figure out why it's leaking.   Maybe there is damage to the roof, or maybe there is a drainage problem and water is just building up and finding its way in. Also possible is that the flashing around a vent or access hole has been bent away and water is getting behind it. Either way, you will first need to investigate and resolve the root problem and then fix it in-line with how it was already constructed.  If the roof is tarred, you are not going to put down some other barrier.

You will without a doubt have to go on the roof to check it out. If you're not comfortable with this, its best to call a roofing expert.

Comment: My roof is flat. I have an idea of roof weathering with tiles. Thus this will help?

Comment: If your roof is flat, you cannot waterproof it with tiles.  You will need to go with one of the many options for flat roofing.  There are many single-ply options, which are the best, there is modified bitumen (torch-down), and there is a typical tar and gravel type system that would suit your needs.  Is there an existing roof system or is it just bare concrete?  If it is bare, how old is this building?

Answer (score 0):

Concrete cannot be the top layer of any roof. Most likely you have just a concrete slab and not roof system (with layers of insulation).What you should do is to cover concrete with metal sheet for example. What is extremely important is that this metal sheet isn't horizontal; it must be under slope. Now if you want to get it done properly you should put some hydro insulation on top of concrete; then thermal insulation and then cover it with metal sheet. Also you should put the gutters, to prevent water damage on other parts of your house. I know that this sounds expensive and complex, but everything else is even more expensive because it will not get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

we usually in pakistan mix mud and wheat straw , fodder the remainings of wheat after crushing. after mixing this in mud clay we put a layer of 3 to 5inches on concrete roof. it is also insulator keeping the roof cool from sun and control room temperature and dont allow water seeping or leakage  but every 10 to 15 year you have to change it. some time it works for 30 years if you make the layer in slop and rain water never dump on it and it flows out from roof.

Comment: Mud and wheat straw...wow, I love this website. I learn something everyday.

Answer (score -1):

Try Blue Bond with tile adhesive. Make it runny and apply it with a roller.

Comment: This seems to be a product specific to India. To make this answer more appropriate for the general audience, can you perhaps generalize the product type?  Is there something unique about this product?

Answer (score -1):

Apply a bitumen primer using a brush and then after drying gas blow an A.P.P Flex material 2 coats

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's hard to understand what you're talking about; a few more sentences of elaboration would really help.